# Cart rule not working for same product with different custom option

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.2

In Magento 2.3, If I added a product 2 times with different custom option value and I have a cart rule with no coupon is: if quantity is >= 20 then 10% coupon should apply.

Now scenario is I have added same product 2 times with different custom option with quantity 10. Now both products quantity is 20 so 10% coupon should apply but its not.

Please any body can suggest what changes I need to do?

[image]

Thank you,
Vijay

Comment: Anybody knows, how can we do?